# Vanilla Javascript - Move Nodes up or down using top left values onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a navigation UI using Vanilla Javascript, CSS and HTML and have got stuck where I need to move div elements up and down and change their top & right position dependant on their cureent state `active` or `inactive`

```js
const diamond = document.getElementById('main-diamond'),
    pointerArrowTop = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-top'),
    pointerArrowRight = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-right'),
    pointerArrowBottom = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-bottom'),
    pointerArrowLeft = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-left'),
    mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover'),
    radius = 200, // The radius of the semi circle
    nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-first]'), // number of nodes in the code
    nodeContainerFirst = document.querySelector('[data-node-level="first"]'), // Get the container of the first level nodes
    nodeWidth = nodes[0].clientWidth, // Defined width of the node
    nodeHeight = nodes[0].clientHeight, // Defined width of the node
    angle = Math.round( 180 / (nodes.length - 1)); // Distance of the gap between nodes;

pointerArrowTop.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "-2px -2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
});

pointerArrowTop.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
    diamond.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
});

pointerArrowTop.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    let activeNode = document.querySelector('[data-state="active"]'),
        inactiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-state="inactive"]'),
        siblingNode = activeNode.nextElementSibling,
        previousSiblingNode = activeNode.previousElementSibling;

    activeNode.setAttribute('style', 'top: -180px; left: -40px');
    activeNode.dataset.state = 'inactive';
    siblingNode.setAttribute('style', 'top: -180px; left: 0px;');
    siblingNode.dataset.state = 'active';

    inactiveNodes.forEach(function(node, index){
        if(previousSiblingNode){
            if(index != 2 && index != 0 && index != 1){
                let leftVal = Math.round(index * -40);
                node.setAttribute('style', 'left: '+leftVal+'px; top: -'+((index+1)+180 *(index))+'px;');   
            }
        }else{
            if(index != 0){
                let leftVal = Math.round(index * -40);
                node.setAttribute('style', 'left: '+leftVal+'px; top: -'+((index+1)+180*(index))+'px;');   
            }
        }
    });
});

pointerArrowRight.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "2px -2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
});

pointerArrowRight.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
});

pointerArrowBottom.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "2px 2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
});

pointerArrowBottom.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
});

pointerArrowLeft.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "-2px 2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
});

pointerArrowLeft.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node, index) {
        let leftVal = Math.round(index * -40);
        node.setAttribute('style', 'left: '+leftVal+'px; top: -'+(index+1)+'px;');
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body.dark-mode {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#15071a,#1a0f29,#1c2b3f,#064a5b) #f7f7f7;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    
}

.d-flex-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.centerPointMarker {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: aqua;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.app-container {
    width: calc(100% - 34px);
 max-width: 960px;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0px 17px;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.p-t-180 {
    padding-top: 180px;
}

main {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 700px;
}

.nav-container {
 width: 114px;
 height: 180px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

    .nav-container  #main-diamond {
        width: 83px;
        height: 83px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #000;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 14px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
        shape-outside: circle();
    }

        .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container {
            position: relative;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            width: 147px;
            height: 147px;
            left: -22px;
            top: -22px;    
        }

            .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow {
                font-size: 8px;
                position: absolute;
                color: #6A696D;
                transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
            }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top {
                    left: 69px;
                    top: 13px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-top-color: #FFF;
                    }               

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right {
                    transform: rotate(90deg);
                    right: 30px;
                    top: 53px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(90deg);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-right-color: #FFF;
                    }      

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom {
                    transform: rotate(180deg);
                    left: 69px;
                    bottom: 45px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(180deg);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }        


                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-bottom-color: #FFF;
                    }


                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left {
                    transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    left: 30px;
                    top: 53px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-90deg);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-left-color: #FFF;
                    }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .center-icon {
                    width: 59px;
                    height: 59px;
                    display: inline-flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    border: 1px solid #6A696D;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 44px;
                    top: 28px;
                    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
                }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .center-icon i {
            font-size: 26px;
            position: relative;
            top: 1px;
        }

.node-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 342px;
    height: 181px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
    .node-container .node-inner-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }

        .node-container .node-inner-container svg.level-diamond {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            float: left;
        }

        .node-container .node-inner-container .node-text {
            width: calc(100% - 50px);
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

    span.node-level-counter {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -5px;
        right: 0px;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.first-level {
    fill: #F6AE3C;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.first-level {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.second-level {
    fill: #69C3C6;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.second-level {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.third-level {
    fill: #6DBD50;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.third-level {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.fourth-level {
    fill: #E4087D;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.fourth-level {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

footer {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.semicircle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a8d572acbe.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="dark-mode">
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2 p-t-180">
                    <div class="nav-container">
                        <div id="main-diamond" style="z-index: 200;">
                            <div class="controls-container">
                                <div class="pointer-arrow top" id="pointer-arrow-top"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="pointer-arrow right" id="pointer-arrow-right"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="pointer-arrow bottom" id="pointer-arrow-bottom"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="pointer-arrow left" id="pointer-arrow-left"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="center-icon">
                                    <i class="fad fa-fingerprint"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 pl-1 p-t-180">
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="active" data-node-number="1">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-1"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">1</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 1 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="2">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-2"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">2</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 2 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="3">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-3"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">3</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 3 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="4">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-4"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">4</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 4 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="5">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-5"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">5</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 5 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="6">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-6"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">6</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 6 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                     
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>                    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see from the example above when a user clicks on the up arrow the 1st node moves to where it ought to but nodes 3 - 6 stack on top of each other clicking the up arrow again should casue node 3 to come in to focus in the middle and 2 to be positioned above it with a `left: -40px` and node 1 above that with a `left: -80px`

I cannot work out how to do this properly and have gone down many dead ends.

I am Using Vanilla javascript as the project doesn't support jQuery. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: cannot find calculate function

Comment: @MrKhan Thanks for reminding me to remove that as it is unused

Comment: Can you please explain the desired behavior step by step? On the 1st click, you want 1st node to become active and move up and to the left as it currently does and all the other nodes to do what (please describe)? On the consequent click, you expect the 2nd node to do what (please describe) and all the other nodes to do what (please describe)? It is really hard to guess your intention and from what I see you basically have incorrect position calculation math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

Your solution is almost correct. Your problem lies in `position: relative` and your `top` value adjustment. On the first click of the `pointer-arrow-top`, you adjust the top values of below-active-node elements such that they are the multipliers of *-180 + index* (`-180px`, `-361px`, etc.). Before diving to the problem further, I suggest revisiting the concept of `position: relative`.

When you adjust the top value of a relatively positioned element, the element is **visually** moved from its actual position. The browser still keeps track of the element's **actual position**. The next siblings are then also placed based on where the previous element's **actual position** (position before being visually moved) and not based on where it visually is. Here's an image to show what I meant by this. I also recommend reading the section [*Relative Positioning* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

[image: Relative positioning]

This is why that when your first element's top value is adjusted to -180px and your second element's top value is adjusted to -180px, it works. However, your third element's top value is adjusted by -182px and your fourth element's top value is adjusted by -363px, causing them to overlap. Think of it this way: -180px means going up by *one level*. When you adjust the fourth element's top value by -363px, you're making it go up by *two levels*; thus making it in the same *level* as the third element (the same logic applies to the fifth and sixth elements). What we want is to adjust every single element to go up by *one level* each time we click on the top arrow.

Now, it's clear that we can fix this by adjusting all elements to go up by one level each click, then add some additional top value based on the index.

---

### Solution

As mentioned, we needn't adjust the top's value multiplied by index. Instead, the top values of all elements need to be the same. Here's a working solution. The main difference from your code (so that it works as intended) is on the `click` listeners. Do try running it ;-) *I added a data-attribute of `data-node-position` to keep track of how much top value I should give to each element.*

```js
const diamond = document.getElementById('main-diamond'),
      pointerArrowTop = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-top'),
      pointerArrowRight = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-right'),
      pointerArrowBottom = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-bottom'),
      pointerArrowLeft = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-left'),
      pointerArrows = document.querySelectorAll('.controls-container [class^="pointer-arrow"]'),
      mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover'),
      radius = 200, // The radius of the semi circle
      nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-first]'), // get all the pillar nodes
      nodeContainerFirst = document.querySelector('[data-node-level="first"]'), // Get the container of the first level nodes
      nodeWidth = nodes[0].clientWidth, // Defined width of the node
      nodeHeight = nodes[0].clientHeight, // Defined width of the node
      angle = Math.round(180 / (nodes.length - 1)) // Distance of the gap between nodes;


function initializeNodes() {
  nodes.forEach(function(node, index) {
    let leftVal = Math.round(index * -40)
    let topVal = -1 * (index + 1)
    
    // You should use transform instead of adjusting top and left values
    // node.style.transform = `translate(${leftVal}px, ${topVal}px)`
    node.style.left = `${leftVal}px`
    node.style.top = `${topVal}px`
    node.dataset.nodePosition = index + 1
    // Limit to two visible nodes on the bottom side
    if (node.dataset.nodePosition > 3) node.style.opacity = '0'
  })
}

function initializePointerArrowsOnHover() {
  const pointerOnHoverBoxShadowValues = {
    'top': '-2px -2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
    'right': '2px -2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
    'bottom': '2px 2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
    'left': '-2px 2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
  }

  pointerArrows.forEach(pointerArrow => {
    let pointerDirection
    if (pointerArrow.classList.contains('top')) pointerDirection = 'top'
    else if (pointerArrow.classList.contains('right')) pointerDirection = 'right'
    else if (pointerArrow.classList.contains('bottom')) pointerDirection = 'bottom'
    else pointerDirection = 'left'

    pointerArrow.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = pointerOnHoverBoxShadowValues[pointerDirection]
    })
    pointerArrow.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null
    })
  })
}

function initializePointerArrowsOnClick() {
  function adjustPositionAndOpacity(clickEvent, direction) {
    const activeNode = document.querySelector('[data-state="active"]'),
          previousActiveNode = activeNode.previousElementSibling,
          nextActiveNode = activeNode.nextElementSibling,
          adjustPositionByValue = direction === 'up' ? -1 : 1,
          // Top value offset by -180 multiplied by the number of elements on the top side after adjusting position
          firstNodePosition = parseInt(nodes[0].dataset.nodePosition),
          topValueOffset = Math.abs((firstNodePosition + adjustPositionByValue - 1)) * -180

    if (direction === 'up' && !nextActiveNode) return
    else if (direction === 'down' && !previousActiveNode) return

    nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
      let newNodePosition = parseInt(node.dataset.nodePosition) + adjustPositionByValue
      node.dataset.nodePosition = newNodePosition

      // Adjust opacity for a fade-in fade-out effect
      // Some nodes are hidden when there is more than one node on the top side and more than two nodes on the bottom side
      if (newNodePosition > 3 || newNodePosition < 0) node.style.opacity = '0'
      // Nodes that are hidden are displayed when they are supposed to be visible
      else node.style.opacity = '1'

      if (newNodePosition === 1) node.dataset.state = 'active'
      else node.dataset.state = 'inactive'

      const leftValue = Math.abs(newNodePosition - 1) * -40
      const topValue = topValueOffset + -1 * newNodePosition
      
      // You should use transform instead of adjusting top and left values
      // node.style.transform = `translate(${leftValue}px, ${topValue}px)`
      node.style.top = `${topValue}px`
      node.style.left = `${leftValue}px`
    })
  }
  
  pointerArrowTop.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    adjustPositionAndOpacity(e, 'up')
  })

  pointerArrowBottom.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    adjustPositionAndOpacity(e, 'down')
  })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  initializeNodes()
  initializePointerArrowsOnHover()
  initializePointerArrowsOnClick()
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body.dark-mode {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #15071a, #1a0f29, #1c2b3f, #064a5b) #f7f7f7;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}

.d-flex-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.centerPointMarker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.app-container {
  width: calc(100% - 34px);
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px 17px;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.p-t-180 {
  padding-top: 180px;
}

main {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 700px;
}

.nav-container {
  width: 114px;
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond {
  width: 83px;
  height: 83px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
/*   margin-left: 14px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px; */
  margin: 14px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
/*   shape-outside: circle(); */
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 147px;
  height: 147px;
  left: -22px;
  top: -22px;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow {
  font-size: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #6A696D;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top {
  left: 69px;
  top: 13px;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top:hover~.center-icon {
  border-top-color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 30px;
  top: 53px;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(90deg);
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right:hover~.center-icon {
  border-right-color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 69px;
  bottom: 45px;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(180deg);
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom:hover~.center-icon {
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: 30px;
  top: 53px;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-90deg);
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left:hover~.center-icon {
  border-left-color: #FFF;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .center-icon {
  width: 59px;
  height: 59px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #6A696D;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 44px;
  top: 28px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-container #main-diamond .controls-container .center-icon i {
  font-size: 26px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.node-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 342px;
  height: 181px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;  
  transition: top 300ms ease, left 300ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
  
  /* Use this instead
  transition: transform 300ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
  */
}

.node-container .node-inner-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.node-container .node-inner-container svg.level-diamond {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.node-container .node-inner-container .node-text {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin-left: 50px;
}

span.node-level-counter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: 0px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
}

svg.level-diamond rect.first-level {
  fill: #F6AE3C;
}

svg.level-diamond text.first-level {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

svg.level-diamond rect.second-level {
  fill: #69C3C6;
}

svg.level-diamond text.second-level {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

svg.level-diamond rect.third-level {
  fill: #6DBD50;
}

svg.level-diamond text.third-level {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

svg.level-diamond rect.fourth-level {
  fill: #E4087D;
}

svg.level-diamond text.fourth-level {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

footer {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.semicircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a8d572acbe.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="dark-mode">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 p-t-180">
          <div class="nav-container">
            <div id="main-diamond">
              <div class="controls-container">
                <div class="pointer-arrow top" id="pointer-arrow-top"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                <div class="pointer-arrow right" id="pointer-arrow-right"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                <div class="pointer-arrow bottom" id="pointer-arrow-bottom"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                <div class="pointer-arrow left" id="pointer-arrow-left"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                <div class="center-icon">
                  <i class="fad fa-fingerprint"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 pl-1 p-t-180">
          <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="active" data-node-number="1">
            <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-1"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">1</text></svg>
              <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
              <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 1 of 6</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="2">
            <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-2"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">2</text></svg>
              <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
              <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 2 of 6</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="3">
            <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-3"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">3</text></svg>
              <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
              <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 3 of 6</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="4">
            <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-4"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">4</text></svg>
              <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
              <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 4 of 6</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="5">
            <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-5"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">5</text></svg>
              <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
              <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 5 of 6</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="6">
            <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-6"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">6</text></svg>
              <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
              <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 6 of 6</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

### Personal Concerns

I saw a few things on your code that concerned me. Here are some:

- You're using a width of `100vw` on body and a height of `100vh`. The height (that does not expand as content grows larger) makes your body have a fixed height and as a result, causes the linear-gradient background to repeat itself. Instead, I've adjusted your body's height to auto. The width makes a horizontal scrollbar appears (because `100vw` does not take into account the width of the vertical scrollbar, so overflow occurs in the x-axis), I've adjusted it to 100% so that the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear
- You're using a fixed value of `max-height: 700px` to hide the overflowing pillars/nodes. This **may** not work well when the node content sizes can change
- You're using a lot of fixed pixel values. Percentage-based values are always more favourable whenever possible
- Some CSS attributes do not have any effects, such as `shape-outside: circle()` and inline style of `z-index: 200` on `#main-diamond`. Also, as a general rule of thumb, avoid inline styles so CSS is more manageable
- Some variable declarations in your JS are not used: `angle`, `nodeHeight`, `nodeWidth`, and `nodeContainerFirst`. I suppose it would be better if you adjust the `max-height` (from point two) to based on *a number of elements* multiplied by `nodeHeight`
- I've also added some transition on your `node-container` so that the navigation feels less jarring
- I've "grouped" the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners so that it's easier to read

Comment: Thanks, brilliant answer very well explained

Comment: @JustinErswell Glad I could help. I know that this is not pertinent to your question (you wanted to use top and left values). However, I would like to add that you *should* use `transform: translate(...)` to move things visually. Aside from the logical stand of point (that you shouldn't mix positioning with design-ish motion), using `transform` actually also positively affects performance. I recommend reading these two: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/ and https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/ for more info

Comment: @JustinErswell I've also added some comments in my JS code and CSS on how you can use `transform` instead of `top` and `left` (it's the same, basically).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
function init(){
  const diamond = document.getElementById('main-diamond'),
  pointerArrowTop = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-top'),
  pointerArrowRight = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-right'),
  pointerArrowBottom = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-bottom'),
  pointerArrowLeft = document.getElementById('pointer-arrow-left'),
  mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover'),
  radius = 200, // The radius of the semi circle
  nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-first]'), // number of nodes in the code
  nodeContainerFirst = document.querySelector('[data-node-level="first"]'), // Get the container of the first level nodes
  nodeWidth = nodes[0].clientWidth, // Defined width of the node
  nodeHeight = nodes[0].clientHeight, // Defined width of the node
  angle = Math.round( 180 / (nodes.length - 1)); // Distance of the gap between nodes;

  pointerArrowTop.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "-2px -2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
  });

  pointerArrowTop.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
      diamond.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
  });

  pointerArrowTop.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    moveNodes(nodes, 'up');
  });
  pointerArrowBottom.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    moveNodes(nodes, 'down');
  });

  pointerArrowRight.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "2px -2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
  });

  pointerArrowRight.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
  });

  pointerArrowBottom.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "2px 2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
  });

  pointerArrowBottom.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
  });

  pointerArrowLeft.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = "-2px 2px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
  });

  pointerArrowLeft.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      diamond.style["boxShadow"] = null;
  });
}

function moveNodes(nodes, direction){
  if((direction=="up" && nodes[5].dataset.index=="0")||(direction=="down" && nodes[0].dataset.index=="0")){return;}
  var left, top;
  nodes.forEach(function(node, index) {
    top = (direction == "up" ? parseInt(node.style.top) - 180 : parseInt(node.style.top) + 180);
    left = parseInt(node.style.left);
    left = (((node.dataset.index <= 0) && direction=="up") || ((node.dataset.index >= 0) && direction=="down") ? left - 40 : left + 40);
    node.dataset.index = (direction=='up' ? parseInt(node.dataset.index) - 1 : parseInt(node.dataset.index) + 1);
    node.setAttribute('style', 'left: '+left+'px; top:'+top+'px;');
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => { init() }, false);
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body.dark-mode {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#15071a,#1a0f29,#1c2b3f,#064a5b) #f7f7f7;
    color: #f7f7f7;

}

.d-flex-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.centerPointMarker {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: aqua;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.app-container {
    width: calc(100% - 34px);
 max-width: 960px;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0px 17px;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.p-t-180 {
    padding-top: 180px;
}

main {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* max-height: 700px; */
}

.nav-container {
 width: 114px;
 height: 180px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

    .nav-container  #main-diamond {
        width: 83px;
        height: 83px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #000;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 14px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
        shape-outside: circle();
    }

        .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container {
            position: relative;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            width: 147px;
            height: 147px;
            left: -22px;
            top: -22px;
        }

            .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow {
                font-size: 8px;
                position: absolute;
                color: #6A696D;
                transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
            }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top {
                    left: 69px;
                    top: 13px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.top:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-top-color: #FFF;
                    }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right {
                    transform: rotate(90deg);
                    right: 30px;
                    top: 53px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(90deg);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.right:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-right-color: #FFF;
                    }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom {
                    transform: rotate(180deg);
                    left: 69px;
                    bottom: 45px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(180deg);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }


                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.bottom:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-bottom-color: #FFF;
                    }


                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left {
                    transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    left: 30px;
                    top: 53px;
                }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-90deg);
                        color: #FFF;
                    }

                    .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .pointer-arrow.left:hover ~ .center-icon {
                        border-left-color: #FFF;
                    }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .center-icon {
                    width: 59px;
                    height: 59px;
                    display: inline-flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    border: 1px solid #6A696D;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 44px;
                    top: 28px;
                    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
                }

                .nav-container  #main-diamond .controls-container .center-icon i {
            font-size: 26px;
            position: relative;
            top: 1px;
        }

.node-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 342px;
    height: 181px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
    .node-container .node-inner-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }

        .node-container .node-inner-container svg.level-diamond {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            float: left;
        }

        .node-container .node-inner-container .node-text {
            width: calc(100% - 50px);
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

    span.node-level-counter {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -5px;
        right: 0px;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.first-level {
    fill: #F6AE3C;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.first-level {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.second-level {
    fill: #69C3C6;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.second-level {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.third-level {
    fill: #6DBD50;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.third-level {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

svg.level-diamond rect.fourth-level {
    fill: #E4087D;
}
    svg.level-diamond text.fourth-level {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

footer {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.semicircle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a8d572acbe.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body class="dark-mode">
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2 p-t-180">
                    <div class="nav-container">
                        <div id="main-diamond" style="z-index: 200;">
                            <div class="controls-container">
                                <div class="pointer-arrow top" id="pointer-arrow-top"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="pointer-arrow right" id="pointer-arrow-right"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="pointer-arrow bottom" id="pointer-arrow-bottom"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="pointer-arrow left" id="pointer-arrow-left"><i class="fas fa-triangle"></i></div>
                                <div class="center-icon">
                                    <i class="fad fa-fingerprint"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 pl-1 p-t-180">
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="active" data-node-number="1" data-index="0" style="left:0px; top:0px">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-1"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">1</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 1 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="2" data-index="1" style="left:-40px; top:-1px">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-2"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">2</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 2 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="3" data-index="2" style="left:-80px; top:-2px">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-3"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">3</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 3 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="4" data-index="3" style="left:-120px; top:-3px">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-4"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">4</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 4 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="5" data-index="4" style="left:-160px; top:-4px">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-5"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">5</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 5 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="node-container" data-first data-state="inactive" data-node-number="6" data-index="5" style="left:-200px; top:-5px">
                        <div class="node-inner-container clearfix">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="level-diamond" data-level="first" data-name="first" id="level-first-6"><rect x="5.95" y="5.95" width="38.1" height="38.1" rx="4.69" transform="translate(-10.36 25) rotate(-45)" class="first-level"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff" class="first-level">6</text></svg>
                            <div class="node-text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus totam, repudiandae dolore.</div>
                            <span class="node-level-counter">Pillar 6 of 6</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </main>
    <footer></footer>  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>                    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide them and make them reappear when you click the buton.